# UTM: issue with setting display parameters

Tags: virtual-machine, utm

Hello stack overflow members,

I try to setup a Windows 10 Pro VM on a Mac, but I have issues setting the Display. Specific are these:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014);
Memory 16 G;
macOS Big Sur 11.7.1;
UTM 4.3.5 (8.7)
```

Standard setup is that when the VM window is resized, the VM content zooms in our out. Instead I would like the display resolution switches in accordance, but that's not what I get.

According to the documentation:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

I don't what means "QEMU backend virtual machines". Also in the documentation:

> [image: Blockquote]

When the VM waS created, Emulated Display Card was set this way:

[image]

I change the Display cad to **virtio-gpu-gl-device (GPU Supported)**.**Resize display to window...** **was not selected**. Starting the VM displayed this error:

[image]

I am completely lost. What does that mean ?

Thanks